# Laravel Broadcasting does't write to redis but direct call to redis works

Tags: laravel, redis, broadcast

I have tried sereval tuto to try to setup Laravel Redis NodeJs Socket.

And it'is not working.

So far :
- my broadcast fires as I can see it in Laravel log
- my redis server works (I have added a call to Redis in my homecontroller and I can see the value in the log and in redis-cli monitor - I have also installed Horizon and I can see its call in Redis-cli monitor)

But when my broadcast fires I don't see anything in redis-cli monitor

I have already tried the obvious things (cache/ config clear / reboot / ...)

Help will be very apreciated !

**Redis call in my homecontroller : working**

```
Redis::set("foo","bar");
$value = Redis::get("foo");
Log::debug('Redis value :'.$value);
```

**.Env**

```
LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=siview
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=


QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync

CACHE_DRIVER=file

SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120


BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

**Database.php**

```
 'redis' => [
        'client' => 'predis',

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
            'read_write_timeout' => 60,
        ],

        'cache' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', 1),
        ],

         'pubsub' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 2,
        ],




    ],
```

**Boadcasting.php**

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Broadcaster
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default broadcaster that will be used by the
    | framework when an event needs to be broadcast. You may set this to
    | any of the connections defined in the "connections" array below.
    |
    | Supported: "pusher", "redis", "log", "null"
    |
    */

    'default' => env('BROADCAST_DRIVER', 'redis'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Broadcast Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define all of the broadcast connections that will be used
    | to broadcast events to other systems or over websockets. Samples of
    | each available type of connection are provided inside this array.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'encrypted' => true,
            ],
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'pubsub',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'driver' => 'log',
        ],

        'null' => [
            'driver' => 'null',
        ],

    ],

];
```

**Event**

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use App\User;


class SendMessageEvent  implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    private $user;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('App.User.' . $this->user->id);
    }

    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        return ['message' => 'Salut ' . $this->user->name];
    }
}
```

**Route Channel**

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Broadcast Channels
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may register all of the event broadcasting channels that your
| application supports. The given channel authorization callbacks are
| used to check if an authenticated user can listen to the channel.
|
*/

Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return true;//(int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

**Route web**

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/


Auth::routes();

    Route::get('/send/{user}', function(\App\User $user){

    event(new \App\Events\SendMessageEvent($user));

    });

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

**Laravel.log showing my broascast**

```
    [2018-11-04 09:39:42] local.INFO: Broadcasting [App\Events\SendMessageEvent] on channels [private-App.User.1] with payload:
    {
        "message": "Salut nathalie",
        "socket": null
    }
```

**redis-cli monitor showing my homecontroller test**

```
1541324518.159040 [0 127.0.0.1:59334] "SELECT" "0"
1541324518.159776 [0 127.0.0.1:59334] "SET" "foo" "bar"
1541324518.160360 [0 127.0.0.1:59334] "GET" "foo"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found and it's a bit strange :

I am working on windows with wamp.

The wamp server was started by not the Laravel server.

Strangly everything seemed to work well (no errors, pages rendered, auth was working...)

I just started laravel with : php artisan serve
and now I can see in Redis-cli monitor :

```
1541328214.873429 [0 127.0.0.1:52962] "SELECT" "2"
1541328214.874260 [2 127.0.0.1:52962] "PUBLISH" "private-App.User.1" "{\"event\":\"App\\\\Events\\\\SendMessageEvent\",\"data\":{\"message\":\"Salut nathalie\",\"socket\":null},\"socket\":null}"
1541328661.366923 [0 127.0.0.1:53078] "SELECT" "2"
1541328661.367643 [2 127.0.0.1:53078] "PUBLISH" "private-App.User.1" "{\"event\":\"App\\\\Events\\\\SendMessageEvent\",\"data\":{\"message\":\"Salut nathalie\",\"socket\":null},\"socket\":null}"
1541328679.554077 [0 127.0.0.1:53083] "SELECT" "2"
1541328679.555197 [2 127.0.0.1:53083] "PUBLISH" "private-App.User.1" "{\"event\":\"App\\\\Events\\\\SendMessageEvent\",\"data\":{\"message\":\"Salut nathalie\",\"socket\":null},\"socket\":null}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have latest version of redis serve.
Laravel uses commands like `eval` that supported in latest version on redis server.
I used `Redis 3.2.100` and issue was solved.

Answer (score -1):

I found that same problem and after a lot of useless research it was as simple to update de redis server.

Download here:
https://redis.io/download

Or here for windows:
https://redislabs.com/ebook/appendix-a/a-3-installing-on-windows/a-3-2-installing-redis-on-window/